# Extract values from lists of dictionaries; With same keys, but different values for each list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries. Something like this.

```
'authors':  [
                [
                    {
                        'name':  'ABC',
                         'ids':  [
                            '144548847'
                        ],
                    }
                     {
                        'text':  'ABC',
                         'fragments':  [

                        ]
                    }
                ],
                 [
                    {
                        'name':  'XYZ',
                         'ids':  [
                            '145715698'
                        ],
                         'slug':  'Xy-z'
                    },
                     {
                        'text':  'X.y.Z',
                         'fragments':  [

                        ]
                    }
                ]
            ]
```

I would like to extract the 'name' of all the authors (There could be more than two authors).
I was only able to get 'ABC' by doing this.

```
for values in results:
    "Author(s) :",values['authors'][0][0]['name']
```

Here results is the **main dictionary** which has values as list of dictionaries and I want to pull out authors' name from that dictionary.

I tried doing the below but it gives me **TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

```
for values in results:
        "Author(s) :",values['authors'][0][0:]['name']
```

Comment: Use `[0]` instead of `[0:]`.

Comment: using [0] only gives me the first name of the author but I would like to extract multiple author names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it using recursion for an arbitrarily structured and deep dataset:

```py
def traverse(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        for v in x:
            traverse(v)
    elif isinstance(x, dict):
        if 'name' in x:
            authors.append(x['name'])
        else:
            for v in x.values():
                traverse(v)
```

```py
>>> authors = []
>>> traverse(values['authors'])

>>> print(authors)
['ABC', 'XYZ']
```

To make it better and more general, you could change the global list `authors` to a local variable and have it created then passed around in the recursion. I'll leave that exercise up to you if you desire that functionality.

Edit: Using only list comprehension:

```py
>>> [y.get('name') for x in values['authors'] for y in x if y.get('name')]
['ABC', 'XYZ']
```

This is less clean and very hard to read however, so I would be careful approaching it this way.

Comment: The results are exactly what I want. Thank you! 
Is there a way to do it without having to define a function. Say a slice operation? or list operations?

Comment: Yeah there's likely a way you could hack it together with list or dict comprehensions, however I don't expect it to be clean nor general if your schema ever changes. I have added it as an edit to my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
for values in results:
    for each in values['authors']:
        name = each.get("name")
        if name:
           print("Author(s) :", name)
```

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Please, improve a bit Your example (format it the proper way) so we can help You better then.